# What does Pod Repo Remove Master do?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

So I am very new to CocoaPods and I want some clarification on a command.

I had an error that said `Unable to find a specification for 'Firebase/Core'` and after multiple tries of different commands the only thing that worked was `Pod repo remove master`. Can anyone tell me why that worked and what it did?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Master(Specs) Repo is the repository on GitHub that contains the list of all available pods. In case it is broken or not up-to-date you might face issues while installing or updating your pods.

By `pod repo remove master` you removed the master repo which might be broken or not up-to-date.

Comment: if this doesn't work it's possible you don't have a local checkout of the corresponding master branch on your system. use 

'pod repo update'